# Error 1146: table '#__content' doesn't exist' in mysql Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1146

Was developing a website using `joomla 3, php 5.4.16, mysql 5.6.12`. Because i have `mysql community` edition installed, they share `port 3306`, so everytime i switch, i have to stop one service and start the other. 
on starting win7 and `wampserver`, i couldnt access `phpmyadmin` so i copied my site and the tables from mysql data and pasted them on desktop, i uninstalled and installed wampserver and copied the folders....
But now it shows the tables on phpadmin sidebar but gives an `error 1146 cannot access table name`.

- i have tried to repair tables but it gives an error in sql syntax
- changed advanced options in `config.inc $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';`
- Created a new databases, copied the tables into it but hasn't worked

How to repair the tables, because the site is too big to start all over

Answer (score 1):

We've had the same issue with a client before - we have really tried everything when it comes to fixing the table. At the end we had to create another, totally new database and then restore the content from a previous daily backup that we had, and then point the Joomla website to that new database. The client lost a bit of data at that time but it was acceptable for him.

After further investigation, we discovered that there was a corruption in core MySQL so we had to uninstall and re-install MySQL on the server, and the re-import the database.

If you tried everything (like really everything) to fix the table and it's not fixed, then just don't use the database anymore and use another one. Also check the instance of MySQL that you have for any corruption, and re-install it if necessary.